# How to load different assets when language change?

Tags: flutter, dart, web

I would need some guidance.
On my page I have a video that loads at startup and I also have a switcher that allows me to change the language, but when changing this language I require that I change the video. Currently the video widget is in a separate file from the home page.

How can I take the change and bring the corresponding video?

Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to either share the state for `language` or pass the `language` variable directly  down to the widget via a parameter of the widgets.

A `cubit` in the bloc pattern would handle this. Take a look at https://bloclibrary.dev/#/fluttercountertutorial

You'd have to make a `LanguageCubit<LanguageEvent, LanguageState>`. For your button's `onPressed` event, send a "LanguageChange" to the `LanguageCubit`.

You'll can then to use a `BlocProvider` and a `BlocBuilder` with the video Widget as the child. The widget will re-render when the LangaugeState is changed and, after you wire it up, you can load the correct video based on the language state.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but actually i solved it with :

@override
  void didUpdateWidget(Video oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);

    if (oldWidget.videoPath != widget.videoPath) {
      _clearPrevious().then((_) {
        initializeVideoPlayer();
      });
    }
  }